# Are there any annotated formal verification systems for pure functional programming languages?

Tags: lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, functional-programming, formal-methods, haskell

[ACSL](http://frama-c.com/acsl.html) (Ansi C Specification Language), is a specification for C code, annotated with special comments, that allows C code to be formally verified.

I have not looked into it, but I imagine that the formal methods used in [ACSL](http://frama-c.com/acsl.html) verifiers would be similar to Hoare Logic. For pure functional languages though, such as Haskell, I can't imagine what sort of formalism would be used for formal verification.

Has anyone made something similar to [ACSL](http://frama-c.com/acsl.html), but for a pure functional language? If not, has there been any research into specification-annotated style formal verification for functional languages?

I know that there's dependent typing, which many languages (Agda, Idris, etc...) support, but in Haskell dependent typing is difficult without doing some (unreadable?) type-wizardry. With that in mind, and since Haskell has so much better library support than Agda and Idris, I believe such a system for functional formal verification might be useful, but I don't know if research has been done on this or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Honda and Yoshida's

- [A Compositional Program Logic for Polymorphic Higher-Order Functions](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~yoshida/paper/polyrec.ps)

(probably) pioneered Hoare logics for purely functional languages. This work is based
on Hennessy-Milner logic and Milner's encoding of functions into processes, as described here:

- [From Process Logic to Program Logic](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~yoshida/paper/icfp04.ps)

The work by Régis-Gianas et al mentioned in another answer is similar to the first work above by Honda/Yoshida. This has been extended to effectful ML-style languages:

- [An Observationally Complete Program Logic for Imperative Higher-Order
  Functions](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/mfb21/publications/icfp05/index.html)
- [A Logical Analysis of Aliasing in Imperative Higher-Order Functions](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~yoshida/paper/alias_jfp.pdf)
- [Logical Reasoning For Higher-Order Functions With Local State](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.2448.pdf)
- [Program Logics for Sequential Higher-Order Control](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/mfb21/publications/fsen09)
- [Program Logics for Homogeneous Meta-Programming](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/mfb21/publications/lpar10)

The logics mentioned are what is called observationally complete, meaning that the operational and the logical semantics coincide. [Arthur Charguéraud](http://www.chargueraud.org/) used this completenss
for his work on verifying functional programs Hoare-style in Coq.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to check out [Liquid Haskell](http://goto.ucsd.edu/~rjhala/liquid/haskell/blog/about/), which allow working with type *refinements* rather than dependent types. Type refinements can be seen as a restricted logical language that allow you to express Hoare-style properties of the inhabitants of various datatypes. Another possible candidate is the [$F^*$ language](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/fstar/), which offers similar constructs.

There seems to be a close correspondence between refinement types and the ACSL like notations.

Finally I can only suggest taking a closer look at Agda and Idris, as they can compile to Haskell, and are aimed at providing the user with a usable programing language (especially Idris). I suspect it's possible to integrate Haskell libraries into Idris code without too much trouble.

Comment: *without too much trouble* - not really. Idris is strict by default, and Haskell is lazy; that alone poses as a major problem. Compatibility with Haskell was also never a very high priority for Idris design.

Comment: Fair enough. Agda checks termination by default though, so things like strictness aren't a problem *in theory*. Of course run-time could be dramatically different.

Answer (score 11):

See also Yann Régis-Gianas PhD thesis work with François Pottier: [A Hoare Logic for Call-by-Value Functional Programs (MPC'08)](http://cristal.inria.fr/~fpottier/publis/regis-gianas-pottier-hoarefp.pdf). This work was extended to cover the usual ML side-effects by Johannes Kanig and Jean-Cristophe Filliatre in 2009: [Who: A Verifier for Effectful Higher-order Programs](http://hal.inria.fr/hal-00777585).

Answer (score 8):

There is a paper in this year's [ICFP](http://icfpconference.org/icfp2014/), [refinement types for Haskell](http://dl.acm.org/authorize.cfm?key=N87776). The paper deals with termination checking rather than full Hoare logic, but hopefully that's a start in this direction.

The related work section in that paper contains some pointers, such as Xu, Peyton-Jones, and Claessen's [static contract checking for Haskell](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/verify/HaskellContract.ps), and Sonnex, Drossopoulou, and Eisenbach's [Zeno](http://pubs.doc.ic.ac.uk/zenoTwo/zenoTwo.pdf) and Vytiniotis, Peyton-Jones, Claessen, and Rosen's [Halo](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/verify/hcc-popl.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Our work on soft verification of contracts is related, at [OOPSLA 2012](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2384655) and [ICFP 2014](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2628156), allows you to write contracts, which are a lot like ACSL specs, and then either statically verify them or use them a dynamic checks at runtime.